# C# - Code not running and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, dictionary, discord

I'm currently creating a Discord bot using Discord.NET, but I don't think that matters here, and I'm trying to do some checks with dictionaries and I've run into the problem that some code doesn't run and I can figure out why. Let me try and summarize the code.

```
private Dictionary<Server, Dictionary<User, ChatterBotSession>> sessions = new Dictionary<Server, Dictionary<User, ChatterBotSession>>();

if (sessions.Any())
{
    if (sessions[e.Server].Any())
    {
        await e.Channel.SendMessage("Sorry, I'm already talking to someone on this server.").ConfigureAwait(false);
        return;
    }
}

ChatterBotFactory factory = new ChatterBotFactory();
ChatterBot.ChatterBot bot = factory.Create();
ChatterBotSession session = bot.CreateSession();

Dictionary<User, ChatterBotSession> sessionDic = new Dictionary<User, ChatterBotSession>();
sessionDic.Add(e.User, session);
sessions.Add(e.Server, sessionDic);

await e.Channel.SendMessage("Added dicionary entry with server '" + e.Server.Name + "' and user '" + e.User.Name + "'");
```

So when this code first gets executed, it goes through and sends the message with the "await e.Channel.SendMessage(...);". And if I execute this code on the same Discord server, it recognizes the server in the dictionary and stops at the "already talking to someone" message. So that's all fine and dandy. But if I then go to another server, it goes through the "sessions.Any()" if and "if(sessions[e.Server].Any())" and since it isn't that server, it doesn't go into that if, but then it just stops! The way I see it, it *should* continue outside the "sessions.Any()" if.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I can't see how this is possible. Have you stepped through this line by line and seen it return from your method immediately after it fails to satisfy your second if condition?

Comment: I can not see that you ever will get into the if statement. With that code the dictionary sessions will be empty when you hit the if statement.

Comment: @TeisLindemark But since I do get into the first if statement, it's not empty. The problem here is that even if it doesn't hit any of the if statements inside, it doesn't continue. It just stops in there.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I've gone through every line with breakpoints in Visual Studio and when it stops working, it just disappears. It goes into the if statement and just disappears.

Comment: Sounds like a silent failure. Try to catch any exceptions around that code - break point in there to figure out whats up. I can only imagine that `e.Server` is the reason

Comment: You check for `sessions.Any()` but wouldn't it be a good idea to check, whether `sessions` actually contains `e.Server`?

Comment: Maybe you can configure visual studio in order to break on exceptions instead of silently failing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx

Comment: @SimpleVar I tried doing it and I got the message that the key was not present. And thanks to grek40's suggestion, I was able to pinpoint the error.

Comment: @grek40 I did that and now I can pinpoint the problem and work around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find a solution. I got the suggestion to wrap it into a try and catch and I found out the key was not present. For some reason, it didn't tell me that. So I then checked if the key was actually present and I'm handling it much better now so the rest of the code is getting executed.

Here's some of the updated code.

```
private Dictionary<Server, ChatSession> sessions = new Dictionary<Server, ChatSession>();

if (sessions.Any())
{
    if (sessions.ContainsKey(e.Server))
    {
        if(sessions[e.Server].User == e.User)
        {
            await e.Channel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " I'm already talking to you! :P");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await e.Channel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + " I'm already talking to someone here. Try again later.");
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await e.Channel.SendMessage("This server is not stored, continuing.");
    }
}
```